# Rails: Logging errors and common request logs into different log files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

here's my question.
I wonder if there's any way writing different levels' of logs in to different log files.
For example:
warnings into warnings.log
errors into errors.log

Does rails support doing this in settings? I really didn't find how.
Any idea?

Thanks a lot !!